# Existing jobs stalled, new jobs failing. Network issue?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Suddenly getting this when trying to start any new jobs:

`2016-02-23T23:42:27.051Z: Error:   (f2984821f598b8e3): Workflow failed. Causes: (175d43386b799a19): Unable to create VMs. Causes: (175d43386b7993ee): Error:
 Message: Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].network': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/link-staging-2/global/networks/default'.  The specified network was not found.
 HTTP Code: 400`

And existing jobs seem to be stalled, not processing any events, 2% cpu usage, ssh timeout to those vm's.

Jobid of stalled job: 2016-02-23_12_48_02-17525521157403139911

Jobid of a failed to start job: 2016-02-23_15_42_20-9421118277209731100

Comment: To confirm, have any changes been made to the networking configuration for your project?

Comment: I assumed not, but it turns out someone was experimenting. That's almost definitely it my bad. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that anyone else is likely to hit this issue, but if you do, it's because someone deleted the default network in GCP. Re-create it.

```
gcloud compute networks create default

gcloud compute routes list
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just try creating any new network and then attaching your instances to that.  Something along the lines of this would also work:

```
gcloud compute networks create whatever

gcloud compute firewall-rules create default --network whatever --allow tcp:22,tcp:80,icmp

gcloud compute instances create test-network-example --zone us-central1-a --project $YourProject \
--image centos-7-v20160711 --image-project centos-cloud --network whatever
```